# Set wordpress query before template

Tags: wordpress

I have a business goal forcing me to try to change the global wordpress query after the URL has been determined, but before the templates start outputting variables in the context of the original post.  I need to be able to use a plugin to check some meta values on the original post, and then change the query to represent another post object to display different data without changing the url.

I've tried using setup_postdata() what seems like everywhere.

```
(tried including wp_reset_query();)
global $post;
$post = get_post(145, OBJECT );
setup_postdata($post);
```

However, the template is still outputting the original query.

I'm open to other solutions.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: More context, please.  Where did you place this code? In a template? Functions.php? Someplace else? How is this code triggered?

Comment: So, I've gotten past this issue by using query_posts (see other answer), however this is breaking the templates whenever a page is being used.

Comment: See my answer below if you're curious.  I just needed p for posts and page_id for pages.  Templates follow when those are set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function(){
    query_posts(array('p'=>145,'post_type' =>'any'));
});
```

This worked out fine.  It can be added just about anywhere. However, it messes up page templates, and displays pages as if they're single.php!!! If I can get around that, then I'll be in good shape.  Help?

EDIT:  Got it working.  I have to check and use p for posts, and page_id for pages.  So long as those are set, the templates will follow correctly.  Otherwise it was trying to apply the standard post template to pages.

Comment: I'm guessing this is likely not the way to accomplish what you were actually after.  You should post your FULL answer, as your question mentions checking meta values, etc.  Let's see what you're doing, and maybe we can help do it in a more efficient / "best practice" manner?